# Problem with ifstream::setbuf in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

What changes are needed when porting "setbuf" in VS2005 to VS2008?

I have to modify a project in VS2005 to VS2008 to be able to build it. Below is the line of code that needs to be compiled in VS2008.

```
 std::ifstream In; 
 In.setbuf(FileBuffer, BUFFER_REGION_SIZE);
```

When I compile the above code in VS2008, I see the below error.

```
 error C2039: 'setbuf' : is not a member of 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

What needs to be done to compile it in VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like `In.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(FileBuffer, BUFFER_REGION_SIZE);`?

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/pubsetbuf/

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it solved my problem.
Thanks Mark.

Comment: Can it be used with both ifstream and ofstream objects?